# Google GMail API Access Not Configured Via Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to follow
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android

To get talking to the GMail API for Google Play.
I have created my project, my credential using the SHA1 from my debug.keystore file. I have double checked the package name is correctly matching. I have verified that Android studio is signing w/ the debug.keystore. I am still getting Access Not Configured when trying to run the example code. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you add your API key to the Manifest ?

Comment: Should we add our API key in the manifest? and API key would be? @MatthieuLemoine. Please assist

Answer (score 0):

I guess, if you have ended up following the documentation, the issue could be:

The build.gradle file in the app module, there, the package name would should point to a different one and not yours. Cross check.

Also try adding couple of other APIs as well, like Contacts and Google+ APIs in console.

It is working for me!